# Is it possible to use tempatetags inside javascript in a django template?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, django-urls

can i use `{% url 'ajax_choice_question' %}` inside javascript in a django template??

For example: How to make this work??

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^ajax/quest/$','getChoices',name='ajax_choice_question'),
```

#### in template

```
<script>
    var urllink="{% url 'ajax_choice_question' %}";
    alert(urllink);
</scritp>
```

---

### update

#### template file

```
{% block extrajavascript %}     
    <script src="/static/js/myjs.js"></script>      
{% endblock %}
```

#### myjs.js

```
var urllink="{% url 'ajax_choice_question' %}";
alert(urllink);
```

Comment: "can i use...?" Well, did you try it?

Comment: @Amadan it won't worked. ie just alerts `{% url 'ajax_choice_question' %}`

Comment: is `getChoices` rendering that template? It should work if so. The template is just text as far as django is concerned. It doesn't matter if your tags are in `script` blocks or not

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony ys what is the problem is i put the script in an external `.js` file. i Updated the question

Comment: @Amadan I updated the question....Now it won't work right.  ok i can use the url `ajax/quest/` ... anyway thanks.. do i need to delete this question???

Comment: Yeah, "in template" and "in static file" are two very different things. Just include it in a template at the top of the `<head>`, and every JS file you include will have access to that variable. You do not need to delete the question, but do take care in the future to ask questions precisely, and with all the relevant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template tags are in an external javascript file (i.e. a file in your `STATIC_ROOT`) then no your template tags won't work, as django doesn't serve those javascript files, your webserver does. Django only serves the rendered results of the template specified in your view, not any related javascript or css files.

If you wanted this to work, you would need to create an url and view to render the javascript with a context and serve it to the client, but this is a very bad idea. You are better off including the relevant javascript in your html file and using your template tags there, or finding another way to pass the results of your template tag to the external javascript

Comment: ok i can use the url ajax/quest/ ... anyway thanks.. do i need to delete this question???

Comment: No you don't need to delete it.